# R is a vector a 1 row matrix or 1 column matrix

Tags: r

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,4,6)
```

Then:

```
c = cbind(a,b)
```

In this case, I expect the result is a 1x6 matrix, but it turns out a 3x 2 matrix

```
d = rbind(a,b)
```

This turns out a 2x3 matrix. Why are the structures of a and b not consistent? What are the underlined rules here?

Comment: it is correct. why do you think `cbind` should give 1x6 matrix ?

Comment: @YOLO, some other languages treat a vector like a 1-row matrix, R is perhaps unique (or at least the behavior is not universal) in this regard. The fact that it has a `NULL` dimension is a direct consequence of this, not the other way around. @VuDuong, `rbind` sees vectors as rows, `cbind` sees them as columns; it's a duality of convenience in R.

Comment: BTW,  to get the object of length 6, use `c(a,b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are plain vectors (not arrays) and `cbind` treats plain vectors (and one dimensional arrays) as columns while `rbind` treats plain vectors (and one dimensional arrays) as rows.

If given 2 dimensional inputs then they do act in the way described in the question.

For example,

```
A13 <- matrix(1:3, 1)  # 1x3 matrix
B13 <- matrix(4:6, 1)  # 1x3 matrix

cbind(A13, B13)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6

rbind(A13, B13)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    2    3
## [2,]    4    5    6

A31 <- matrix(1:3, 3)  # 3x1 matrix
B31 <- matrix(4:6, 3)  # 3x1 matrix

rbind(A31, B31)
##      [,1]
## [1,]    1
## [2,]    2
## [3,]    3
## [4,]    4
## [5,]    5
## [6,]    6

cbind(A31, B31)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    4
## [2,]    2    5
## [3,]    3    6
```